# useSelector value is still null inside handleSubmit button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

My code flow is that a user fills the form and submits it which goes to action calling the API and then it returns the `postId` and stores it in the reducer. Now my main React component has `useSelector` to get the latest state for the `postId`. So after calling the action and submitting the form I am doing the navigate to that post through `'/classifieds/{postId}'` but `postId` shows null inside the `handleSubmit` function whereas it shows the value of `postId` outside that function. So probably my way of thinking is wrong. Can someone help me in suggesting how should be the flow?

classifieds.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TextEditor } from "../../../components/Text-Editor/text-editor";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import InputGroup from 'react-bootstrap/InputGroup';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getCategories, postClassifieds } from "../../../redux/actions/classifiedsAction";
import './post-classified.scss'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const PostClassified = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const classifiedsLoading = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.loading);
  const postId = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.postId);
  console.log("postID is 1",postId) //  this shows up with the id when handleSubmit is called
  
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;
    const inputValue = type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: inputValue });
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    heading: '',
    category:''
  });

  const [formSubmitMessage, setFormSubmitMessage] = useState(false);

  const newFormData = new FormData();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormSubmitMessage(false);
      
    newFormData.append("heading",formData.heading);
    newFormData.append("category",formData.category);
    await dispatch(postClassifieds(newFormData));
    console.log("postID is 2",postId) //  this shows up null
    navigate(`/classifieds/${postId}`)
  };

  return (
    <div className="section properties">
      <div className="container">
        {classifiedsLoading
          ? (<></>)
          : <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data" className="form-post">
            {/* form.............. */}
          </Form>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

classifiedsAction.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const POST_SUCCESS = "POST_SUCCESS";
export const POST_FAILURE = "POST_FAILURE";
export const CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING = "CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING";

// post classified
export const postClassifieds = (formData) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/posts', formData);
    dispatch({
      type: 'POST_SUCCESS',
      payload: response.data._id, // Assuming the server returns the new document's ID
    });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("error is", error);
    dispatch({
      type: 'POST_FAILURE',
      payload: error.message,
    });
  }
};

// Classifieds loading
export const setClassifiedsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING,
  };
};
```

classifiedsReducer.js

```js
import {
  CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING,
  POST_SUCCESS,
  POST_FAILURE
} from "../actions/classifiedsAction";
  
const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  postID: null,
  error: null
};
  
export const ClassifiedsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        postId: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case POST_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the submit handler has a stale closure over the selected `postId` state.

Update the code such that your `postClassifieds` action returns a resolved value to the calling code that can be awaited.

Example:

```js
export const postClassifieds = (formData) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post('/posts', formData);

    dispatch({
      type: 'POST_SUCCESS',
      payload: data._id,
    });

    return data._id; // <-- return postId to UI/calling code
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("error is", error);

    dispatch({
      type: 'POST_FAILURE',
      payload: error.message,
    });

    throw error; // <-- re-throw error for UI/calling code
  }
};
```

Wrap the asynchronous logic in a `try/catch` to handle the returned `postId` value or any thrown errors or Promise rejections.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    setFormSubmitMessage(false);
    const newFormData = new FormData();
    newFormData.append("heading", formData.heading);
    newFormData.append("category", formData.category);

    const postId = await dispatch(postClassifieds(newFormData));

    // Success if we get this far 
    console.log("postID is 2",postId);
    navigate(`/classifieds/${postId}`);
  } catch(error) {
    // handle/ignore fetch failures/etc
  }
};
```

Comment: Drew your answer worked perfectly fine! I have one doubt why do we use useSelector then? and why does it return stale data that also only inside the function? Can you tell me about that?

Comment: @khemangarg We use the `useSelector` hook when we want to reference the selected state in the component, usually for rendering purposes. Or like the other answer here, perhaps you want to run a side-effect when that value changes. It's entirely possible to only need the value in the callback, as in your code/use case.

Comment: @khemangarg See [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for a more in-depth explanation, but the basic gist is that inside the callback function scope a sort of "copy" of `postId` is kept from the time it's called which can't/won't be updated by reference for the life of the callback function. The store needs to update and the component needs to rerender in order for the `useSelector` hook to run again and pick up any changes. While this *can* happen for the component while the async function is running, the function can't get the updated value.